# Maven BOM Pattern, can it support inheritance

Tags: maven, maven-bom

Can a bill of materials in one project inherit and then extend from a BOM in another application.

Answer (score 0):

A BOM can have another BOM as parent. Then the dependencyManagement is inherited.

Comment: Do you have any examples on how to implement this, as currently its not working for me.

Comment: Then ask a new question with your BOM and what is not working.